# JQuery Persistent Countdown with Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery countdown which I took from [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/source/browse/trunk/src/jquery.countdown.js) and tried to modify with cookie to get persistent result as following:
**Edited**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
   function countdown(el, options) {
    var calc = function (target, current) {
        var o = {};

        var datetarget = getCookie('Target');
        if(!datetarget) {
            clearInterval(cd.id);
            var datetarget = target.getTime()/1000;
        }
        if(datetarget <= 0) { return true; }
        deleteCookie('Target');
        o.seconds = datetarget;
        o.seconds %= 86400;
        o.hours = Math.floor(o.seconds/3600);
        o.seconds -= o.hours * (3600);
        o.minutes = Math.floor(o.seconds/60);
        o.seconds -= o.minutes * (60);
        o.seconds %= 60;
        datetarget -= 1;
        setCookie('Target',datetarget,1);
        return o;
    };
```

It somehow worked but i still got float instead of integer on "seconds" part and wrong result on "hours". Any ideas?

Comment: Why cookies? You can use the `localStorage` object.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: how can i do it with localStorage? or perhaps, i was wrong to put setCookie and getCookie?

Comment: To set: `localStorage.setItem( 'item-name', 'item-value' );`; to get: `localStorage.getItem( 'item-name' );`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Ok, thanks. Anyway, I have chosen to use cookie since after googled, I found that it will be a server side. It's different from client side which has better localStorage usage. CMIIW. However, I have changed my codes but I still found problem with seconds. Since I still got float number instead of integer. Please see my edited codes above.

Comment: Please format your code readable if you want us to debug it. Also, you should put date formatting, countdown loop, jQuery plugin etc in different sections. Only bother us with the non-working part.

Comment: @Bergi: Please see modified codes above. thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't see wrong hours. Which result would you expect for which `datetarget` example that you don't expect?

Comment: Why don't you use a proper Date Object and use `getSeconds() / getMinutes() / getHours()`?

Comment: @Christoph: For a countdown, you usually need to display a date *difference* in seconds - which is not a date value. Only for a clock (to show a [date]time) you'd use a `Date` object. However, I'm not sure what the OP wants either :-)

Comment: @Bergi That's a fair point...I wasn't thinking enough and just wondering why one would do it so complicated;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I still got float instead of integer on "seconds" part

You never rounded it. While the milliseconds you got from [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) were an integer, you got a float with 3 decimals after dividing by 1000 to convert to seconds.

Also, the [EcmaScript Modulus operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.5.3) does work on floats, instead of truncating operands and result to integers. To cite the spec:

> In C and C++, the remainder operator accepts only integral operands;
>   in ECMAScript, it also accepts floating-point operands.
>
> The result of a floating-point remainder operation as computed by the
>   % operator is not the same as the “remainder” operation defined by
>   IEEE 754. The IEEE 754 “remainder” operation computes the remainder
>   from a rounding division, not a truncating division, and so its
>   behaviour is not analogous to that of the usual integer remainder
>   operator. Instead the ECMAScript language defines % on floating-point
>   operations to behave in a manner analogous to that of the Java integer
>   remainder operator; this may be compared with the C library function
>   fmod.
>
> Where neither an infinity, nor a zero, nor NaN is involved […], the
>   floating-point remainder r from a dividend n and a divisor d is
>   defined by the mathematical relation r = n − (d * q) where q is an
>   integer that is negative only if n/d is negative and positive only if
>   n/d is positive, and whose magnitude is as large as possible without
>   exceeding the magnitude of the true mathematical quotient of n and d.
>   r is computed and rounded to the nearest representable value using
>   IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode.

That last part also explains why we likely get some other decimals from small rounding errors in the [floating point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

You may omit one of the equivalent lines

```
    o.seconds -= o.minutes * (60);
    o.seconds %= 60;
```

and add one of

```
    o.seconds = Math.round(o.seconds);
    o.seconds = Math.floor(o.seconds);
```

> wrong result on "hours"

I can't see that. Might it be possible that you did expect the value behave according your timezone? `getTime` returns milliseconds since epoch, which is in *UTC*.